# How BGPView.io determines traffic direction

Tags: router, bgp

I'm interested in how https://bgpview.io/asn/19551 got this information:

> TRAFFIC RATIO: Mostly Outbound

I'd like to get more information about an ASN than is available on bgpview.io.

I didn't find any external source which allows me to get this information, what could I try?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of information is not written anywhere. This is the result of a good guess based on multiple parameters, like the company name, the service they offer, etc. For instance, an ASN assigned to Cloudflare will have a traffic direction Mostly Outbound and a traffic speed of 100GB+.

There is obviously a lot of work behind this information, which is almost completely manually added.

Comment: @user374227 if my answer satisfies your question, can you flag this question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

BGPView.io takes this information from peeringdb.com

I can confirm this since I have my own AS212000 and when I defined my Traffic Ratio on peeringdb.com it got updated on BGPView.io as well.